# Generate and load JSON dump in modern browsers?

Tags: javascript, json, html

I am writting a Web app that can save or open a JSON object, what's the best practice to make it behave exactly like an offline desktop app? Should the JSON dump just be in plain text or something?

Could it function properly even if there is no network connection? This means we have to use pure client side Javascript generate a savefile/openfile dialog box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now have the proper technology to do this:

1. open dialogs: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/
2. save JSON data: something like `data://application/json;base64,eyJkYXRhIjogImhlbGxvLCBqc29uISJ9`
3. native json parse https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_native_JSON

Answer (score 1):

You can use localStorage API of modern browsers to save all your needed data.

localStorage gives you ability to store offline data, but make sure that your data fits within quota.

Also keep in mind that native JSON support can be handy in this case (like JSON.stringify()).

Here are some links that might be useful:

[JSON in JS](http://www.json.org)

[localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/dom/storage#localStorage)

Comment: Could I use something other than localStorage? I need the data to be exported and portable.

Comment: What you mean by "exported and portable"? All data that is stored in json structures are "portable" in scope of json syntax because it's in serialized form, and you can easily get data from localStorage back.

Comment: because, like the JSON dump needed to be carried to a different machine using a usb key ?

Comment: If you need to pull out all your data in json you can use JSON.stringify(). All that data is simple (utf8 or unicode which is utf16 i think - not sure about this ) text so you can grab it, paste into your file on usb key, and restore it later.

Comment: You can't access file system, because of security reasons (javascript sandbox). Maybe this will be helpful http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/